# Searching and filtering array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets say I have an array like this:

```
var arr = ['hello, my', 'hello, my name is', 'hello, my name is newton', 'hello, his', 'hello, his name is', 'hello, his name is pluto', 'hello, she is britney'];
```

I want to filter it into:

```
var arr = ['hello, my name is newton', 'hello, his name is pluto', 'hello, she is britney'];
```

I don't know how to put this but the condition is like if an array element's string can be found on other element then it should be removed. Like 'hello, my' can be found exactly in the next following element 'hello, my name is' so 'hello, my' should be removed.

The actual array I'm trying to filter is:

```
var arr = ['11 22 13', '11 22 13 34', '11 22 13 34 15', '11 22 13 34 35', '11 22 23', '11 22 23 34', '11 22 23 34 15', '11 22 23 34 35', '31 22 13', '31 22 13 34', '31 22 13 34 15', '31 22 13 34 35', '31 22 23', '31 22 23 34', '31 22 23 34 15', '31 22 23 34 35'];
```

I've tried to break it into different groups but I still do not know what to do with it. I'll show it anyway:

```
var threelink = [];
var fourlink = [];
var fivelink = [];

    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i].length>8&&arr[i].length<12){
            fourlink.push(arr[i]);
        }
        else if(arr[i].length>11){
            fivelink.push(arr[i]);
        }
        else { 
            threelink.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: is the array kind of sorted?

Comment: yes it is sorted by something like parents and children. like 'hello, my' is the grandfather, 'hello, my name is' is the father and finally 'hello, my name is newton' is the child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain old nested loops solution, probably faster than the alteratives in this thread because the inner loop looks at a shrinking portion of the array:

```
function uniqueContents(arr) {
    var work = arr.slice(), result = [],
        i, j, l = arr.length, found;

    work.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.length > b.length;
    });

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (!work[i]) break;
        found = false;
        for (j = i + 1; j < l; j++) {
            if (!work[j]) break;
            found = work[j].indexOf(work[i]) > -1;
            if (found) break;
        }
        if (!found) result.push(work[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Other than that this is side-effects free (does not distort the input) and tolerant of null/undefined values.

Comment: what do you mean does not distort the input?

Comment: The solution by James Jithin re-sorts the input array in-place, which might have negative effect on code that runs later. Functions should not silently modify their arguments.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want

```
arr.filter(function(e, i, a) {
  return !a.some(function(e2) {
    return e2 !== e && e2.includes(e);
  });
})
```

This says to filter the array, keeping only elements for which there are NO (`!some`) other elements which include it (but are not equal to it).

It's a little more compact with ES6 arrow functions:

```
arr.filter((e, i, a) => !a.some(e2 => e2 !== e && e2.includes(e)));
```

```js
var arr = ['hello, my', 'hello, my name is', 'hello, my name is newton', 'hello, his', 'hello, his name is', 'hello, his name is pluto', 'hello, she is britney'];

var filtered = arr.filter((e, i, a) => !a.some(e2 => e2 !== e && e2.includes(e)));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: have you tested it? it doesn't work for me? also I'm still trying to understand it

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and  [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), for checking if a string is in the result set to filter off and if the actual value is to insert into the result set.

This works for unsorted data.

```js
var arr = ['hello, my', 'hello, my name is', 'hello, my name is newton', 'hello, his', 'hello, his name is', 'hello, his name is pluto', 'hello, she is britney', 'abc', 'ab'],
    result = arr.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        var push = true;
        r = r.filter(function (b) {
            push = push && b.indexOf(a) === -1;
            return a.indexOf(b) === -1;
        });
        push && r.push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to remove all elements from `array1` which do not appear in `array2`, you can use something like this:

```
var array1 = ['hello, my', 'hello, my name is', 'hello, my name is newton', 'hello, his', 'hello, his name is', 'hello, his name is pluto', 'hello, she is britney'];
var array2 = ['hello, my name is newton', 'hello, his name is pluto', 'hello, she is britney'];

for(var i = 0; i < array.lengh; i++){
    if(array2.indexOf(array1[i]) == -1){
        array1.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Let's hope i understood your problem properly and it helps

Comment: no i'm afraid this is not the answer. Because i do not know which elements is going to be in array2

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var arr = ['11 22 13', '11 22 13 34', '11 22 13 34 15', '11 22 13 34 35', '11 22 23', '11 22 23 34', '11 22 23 34 15', '11 22 23 34 35', '31 22 13', '31 22 13 34', '31 22 13 34 15', '31 22 13 34 35', '31 22 23', '31 22 23 34', '31 22 23 34 15', '31 22 23 34 35'];

arr.sort();
var filterArray = new Array();
for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(i + 1 == arr.length) {
    filterArray.push(arr[i]);
  } else {
    if(arr[i+1].startsWith(arr[i])) {
        continue;
    } else {
        filterArray.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
}
alert(filterArray);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jithin4u/3kzpkLde/)